# What is the verbatim definition of "stigmergy" from Oxford dictionary or similar?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for the verbatim definition of the neologism "stigmergy" from the Oxford or other established dictionary including the phonetic transcription.

There is a definition on wiktionary but I'm looking for a more formal source.

If anyone has access to an extended dictionary that contains the word it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***stigmergy*** /'stɪgmərdʒi/ Entomology
>   [ad. Fr. *stigmergie* (P.-P. Grassé 1959, in *Insectes Sociaux* VI. 62),
>   from Gk. *stigm-oi* pricking + *erg-on* work: see -y3. ]
>   The process by which the results of an insect's activity act as a stimulus to further activity.
>
> 1959 tr. P.-P. Grassé in *Insectes Sociaux* VI. 79 *The stimulation of the workers by the very performances they have achieved is a significant one inducing accurate and adaptable response, and has been named stigmergy*.
>   1965 *Symp. Zool. Soc. Lond*. XIV. 128 *Experimental evidence would seem to be desirable before accepting stigmergy as the explanation of all co-ordinated constructional behaviour*.
>   1981 *Atlantic Monthly* July 49 *There is a similar phenomenon in entomology known as stigmergy.*
>
> Hence *stig'mergic* a.
>
> 1970 G. Ordish tr. R. Chauvin's *World of Ants* i. 41 *At some point there seems to be a brake on the stigmergic process when the stimulation has gone beyond a certain stage.*
>   1971 E. O. Wilson *Insect Societies* xi. 229/2 *Stigmergic responses are evidently major elements in nest construction by social insects*.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask where you found it?

Comment: @user4904: It's OED (the Oxford English Dictionary). The actual page I see online has **Derivatives**, not **Hence** 5 lines up from the end, but presumably John altered that while making the typefaces readable here.

Comment: No, probly that's a change in the newest edition. This is the Second Edition, programmed at Michigan back in the 70s. The language hasn't changed **that** much. It's a **much** cleaner interface, and it will give you all of the example quotations, with source,(usually 4.000-50,000 per word for ordinary words) for any entry. Very nice, but available only to UM people (I think).